# NSDate in NSUserdefaults

Tags: objective-c, syntax, nsdate

This is a question out of curiosity, rather than out of necessity:

If I store an NSDate in my NSUserpreferences, it is stored as follows:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Start</key>
    <date>2016-02-25T09:04:21Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I retrieve the value with

```
NSDate * StartDate =[userDefaults objectForKey:@"Start"];
```

I conveniently get an NSDate.

However, when I want to initialize an NSDate manually, I have to go through an inconvenient hoopla like this:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [comps setMinute:18];
    [comps setHour:17];
    [comps setDay:25];
    [comps setMonth:2];
    [comps setYear:2016];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate *StartDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Now, considering, that somehow

> 2016-02-25T09:04:21Z

is enough information for Objective-C to define an NSDate, **why can't I do something like**

```
NSDate* startDate = @"2016-02-25T09:04:21Z";
```

Or maybe

```
NSDate* startDate = [NSDate datefromString:@"2016-02-25T09:04:21Z"];
```

I know I can take such a string, and define an NSDateformatter, etc. I also know that there are quite a few intrinsic [hassles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) with dates and time. However, if a simple string from a .plist is enough, why can't I do that myself?

Thanks for your insights

Comment: Since strings representing dates - even your ISO8601 formatted one - can have dozens of different formats there is no common method. `NSDateFormatter` is the recommended class for that purpose. Your mentioned hassle is that `NSDate` doesn't consider time zones and that the result of `NSLog/print` is often different from your expectation but displays actually the correct information.

Comment: Still, (and I shouldn't have put the Gregorian Calendar part in my question), that very string is apparently internally enough to work with. I realize that I need to contextualize the NSDate elsewhere in my code, but for simple initialization, it would be nice to just use such a string. Not in the least, because it makes the code quite readable.

Comment: You're free to write a category of `NSDate` to convert the string to date and vice versa